# SQL Server : migrate primary key Id's to new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm planning to migrate some data over from an old user database table to a new one. The old table has an ID column but is not actually a primary key, and isn't linked to other tables through foreign keys etc.

The new database does have proper PK identities, and also has (for argument's sake) a `location` identity table so when migrating over the data I'll need to convert `Table1.Location` to `Table2.LocationId`

The big issue is that I need to maintain the ID PK value for each `User` in the new database, so is there a way to pull across all the data while creating the same key values AND also ignore the rows that have been deleted from the original table?

Table 1 - the original user database

```
Id | Name | Location
---+------+---------
 1   Jim    France
 4   Baz    Germany
 6   Bob    Spain
```

Table 2 - the new database location Id's

```
Id | LocationName
---+-------------
 1     France
 2     Germany
 3     Spain
```

Table 3 - the new database for users

```
Id | Name | LocationId
---+------+-----------
```

Currently empty but would like to end up with:

```
Id | Name | LocationId
---+------+-----------
 1   Jim    1
 4   Baz    2
 6   Bob    3
```

My current tactic is to create e.g. 6 new rows with all NULL values and then do a join like

```
UPDATE t3 
SET t3.Name = o.Name,
    t3.LocationId = l.Id
FROM Table3 AS t3
JOIN Table1 AS o ON o.Id = t3.Id
JOIN Table2 AS l ON l.LocationName = t1.Location
```

Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Why would you create six rows?

Comment: Because I need to get the PK's up to 6 so it tallies with the old keys

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `insert`:

```
insert into t3 (id, name, locationid)
    select t1.id, t1.name, t2.locationid
    from t1 join
         t2
         on t2.locationnname = t1.location;
```

I don't see why you would insert rows, just to overwrite the values.

Comment: This won't retain the PK values of the users though, will it? I still need 1,4 and 6 as the users' pk

Comment: @jamheadart . . . Then make that part of the `insert`.